# Using traits in C++

Tags: c++, templates, traits, const-correctness

This question is related to my last [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303188/const-correctness-and-return-values-c). I am trying to solve the problem using  `traits<T>`  and `traits<T*>`. Please consider the following code.

```
template<typename T>
struct traits
{
    typedef const T& const_reference;
};

template<typename T>
struct traits<T*>
{
    typedef const T const_reference;
};

template<typename T>
class test
{
public:   
    typedef typename traits<T>::const_reference const_reference;
    test() {}   
    const_reference value() const {
        return f;
    }
private:
    T f;
};

int main()
{
    const test<foo*> t;
    const foo* f = t.value(); // error here. cannot convert ‘const foo’ to ‘const foo*’ in initialization
    return 0;
}
```

So it looks like compiler is not considering the traits specialization for pointers and taking return type of `value()` as `const foo` rather than `const foo*`. What am I doing wrong here?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specialization is being used. `traits<foo*>::const_reference` *is* `const foo`. If you want it to be a pointer, use:

```
template<typename T>
struct traits<T*>
{
    typedef const T* const_reference;
};
```

With this, `traits<foo*>::const_reference` will be `const foo*`.

Note that the use of `T` in the `traits<T*>` specialization is completely separate from the T in the `traits` template. You could rename it:

```
template<typename U>
struct traits<U*>
{
    typedef const U* const_reference;
};
```

and you'll have the same specialization. It makes more sense if you've experience in functional programming.

To start, think of the `template <typename ...>` as introducing an abstraction, rather like a function abstracts out a value. It's like turning

```
sum = 0
for item in [1,2,3]:
    sum += item
```

into:

```
function sum(l):
    sum = 0
    for item in l:
        sum += item
    return sum
```

where `l` takes the place of `[1,2,3]`. We can call `sums` from another function that itself has a formal parameter named `l`:

```
function sumsq(l):
    return sum(map(lambda x: x*x, l))
```

`sumsq`'s "l" has nothing to do with `sum`'s "l".

With templates, we abstract type names rather than values. That is, we turn:

```
struct traits {
    typedef const double& const_reference;
};
```

into:

```
template <typename T>
struct traits {
    typedef const T& const_reference;
};
```

Now consider a non-template specialization:

```
template <>
struct traits<double*> {
    typedef const double* const_reference;
};
```

Here there are no template parameters for the specialization, but you can think of `traits<double*>` as applying a `traits` template to a `double*`. Abstract out the `double` and you have:

```
template <typename T>
struct traits<T*> {
    typedef const T* const_reference;
};
```

Here the `T` is a parameter for the specialization, not the base template.

Comment: I feel dump :( But, T itself is a pointer (`foo*`). So specifying `T*` will lead into `T**`?

Comment: No. In the `traits<T*>` specialization, `T` isn't a pointer, `T*` is a pointer. That you use the same typename parameter is inconsequential.